# Console script entry point not accessible with pip -e and windows

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm developing a package and would like to test it locally. I found `pip install -e ./` and it has been working well. However, I'm trying to set up `console_scripts` entry points with my `setup.py` and they are not working. The Windows CMD gives a standar message: `'script' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

[To](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) - [my](https://amir.rachum.com/blog/2017/07/28/python-entry-points/) - [knowledge](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point), those console scripts should register themselves as pure command line tools. Even on Windows an `.exe` file should be created.

I made a minimal case with a `script.py` with a `setup.py`. After running `pip install -e ./` the module was installed correctly, but again the function I registered was not there.

Is there anything I'm missing?

#### Edit: files

```
# setup.py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='script',
    entry_points={
        'console_scipts': [
            'test_entry = script:func'
        ]
    }
)

# script.py
def func():
    print('Hello World :(')

# And command line call:
test_entry
```

#### Edit II:

Running `python setup.py develop` doesn't work. **Neither does `pip install ./`...** I'm beginning to get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix: `'console_scipts'` -> `'console_scripts'`. Missed **r**.